# Application crashing on some devices because "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Crash Reporting and Firebase Remote Config. Version of both is 9.8.0.

On most devices setup works perfectly (I followed [Set up crash reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#set_up_crash_reporting)). But on small percentage of devices (it is actually crash with the highest occurrence) it crashes when I try to initialize Remote Config in Application onCreate method.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.company.application.AppApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.company.application. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.company.application. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.a.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.application.d.a.a(SourceFile:21)
    at com.company.application.AppApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:76)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6426)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Can edit your question and add the application class's oncreate method? (I'm wondering if you "made sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.")

Comment: @petey You don't have to do that - see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html?m=1

Besides, I it was the issue, then it would crash all the time and not only on small percentage of devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to version 10.0.0, Firebase Crash created an additional process in your app named `background_crash`.  An instance of your `AppApplication` class is created and executed for each process in your app, including `background_crash`.

If you want to perform initialization of Firebase services in your application class, you need to add a guard to prevent the initialization from being performed in background_crash.  On way to do that is:

```
    if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        // Not in crash process.  Do your Remote Config init here.
    }
```

Another solution is to upgrade to the latest version of Firebase, 10.0.1.

Assuming this answer is valid, I can't explain why the failure only occurs on some devices, unless the version of Google Play Services installed on the device is a factor, and the failing devices have an older version.

Comment: "unless the version of Google Play services...": unlikely; more likely is that there is a race condition caused by `initializeApp()` not finishing before Remote Config is accessed.

Comment: Hi I am still getting this issue, this issue causing from my android studio only, from other system code is running without crash.

Comment: I am having similar issues with MyApplication.onCreate(). How can I check if an additional process is created by some of my libraries?

Comment: @Sébastien: I don't have a simple answer for you.  Suggest you add some log statements to your Application class and look for multiple instances of the output in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

1. set classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in dependencies.
2. Implement the androidTestImplementation dependencies :

   ```
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:.2.2',
   ```

   > {
   >               exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   >           })